# Restricting Client Access to Node.js/Express Application

Tags: node.js, http, authentication, express

I have created a Node.js application that edits a MongoDB database when an iOS app makes an HTTP request to the server. The iOS app makes requests to certain routes specified by Express to indicate how the database will be edited. When the server is up and running, any client can make these HTTP requests that will result in editing the database. What is a simple way to authenticate that the HTTP request is coming from my iOS app, rather than anywhere from around the web?

Answer (score 0):

[Passport](http://passportjs.org/) is a popular auth library that would help you accomplish your goal (using oauth or one of their other auth strategies).